# Holding splash screen until X Server is ready using dbus

Tags: linux, yocto, dbus

I'm building a small Linux system with the help of Yocto. It is a small PC with a display attached to it and the idea is to boot up and start my application which shows some information.

In order to increase user experiance I would like the splash screen to stay until my application (which needs Xserver to run) is ready.

I'm using pslash for splash screen. I vaguely remember someone saying you could use dbus for a problem like this. But I cannot find that information again and I have no experience with dbus.

So I guess what I'm asking if dbus is the right approach and if there is another/better way to implement this.

Thanks

Comment: how do you execute psplash? do you have systemd unit or init.d script? can we see them?

Comment: I'm using the pre-compiled init.d script that comes when you install psplash via Yocto: https://pastebin.com/Yw5asTqx